# Data wont show in ListView [Android]

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Long story short I have an Android app that grabs data from database, parses it (JSON) and displays it in the ListView on activity_main.xml. Everything works fine as long as I don't add Navigation Drawer to my app. If I add it and edit the code so that listview from menu2_layout is populated, I get a blank page once I open the app and click on menu2.

My file structure:

Java
MainActivity
menu1_Fragment
menu2_Fragment
menu3_Fragment
NavigationDrawerFragment

Layout
activity_main
fragment_main
fragment_navigation_drawer
list_item
menu1_layout
menu2_layout
menu3_layout

Here's my MainActivity code(I've posted it on pastebin since it pretty long):
http://pastebin.com/iqKbw2FH

Hopefully someone already dealt with this problem before.

Thanks in advance guys, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml layout's code.

Comment: Try posting only what is relevant instead of everything. Don't make us have to go elsewhere to see your code.